# tableau server error: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, sockets, tableau-api

I'm trying to install the tableau server on ubuntu server.
Since 80 port is already bounded by other process, I start server on `port 8850`. I tried to create an initial user by `tabcmd initialuser --server 'localhost:8850 --username "code" --password="erDsd3ffds2!"`
But it said "`java.net.SocketException:Unexpected end of file from server` 
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I have come across the situation before.
The problem lies in here.
You are indicating the wrong port number. Instead of `8850`, you need to point your `Gateway Port`.